# Lotus Notes 7 - Eliminate borders from hotspot button on page

Tags: button, border, lotus-notes

I have a page contained by a frame from a frameset. This page contains 3 pictures in which I added Default Hotspots. All 3 of them have a formula in its Click event something like this: `@PostedCommand([OpenFrameset];"frame")`

The page also have an jpeg image as its background.

When I run the frameset, in the frame that contains the 3 hotspots, the first one has some dots style border, like it is focused .... Is there any solution to eliminate this border for all the 3 hotspot buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question border shows only for first hotspot. That is because it gets the focus opening frame.

The question is how to avoid the focus on hotspot?

An easy workaround is to add an additional action hotspot as first hotspot in page. It is based on a space char with font size 1 and has formula "". Then the focus is set to this hotspot and it is almost invisible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! So, I add an hotspot button and it should be hidden?

Comment: I selected a space char with font size 1 and then I should add an hotspot button I guess, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the properties of the related hotspot. There should be an option to disable the border.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! But it is not an Action HotSpot

Comment: It is a picture inserted on a page and then I added a default hotspot on it.

Comment: ah ok. Knuts response is best answer then.